# How to use custom query hooks inside useQueries in react-query

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I created custom hooks for get requests from the server. Below is an example

```
const usePost = (id: string) => {
    return useQuery(['posts', id], () => getPost(id))
}
const usePosts = () => {
    return useQuery(['posts'], () => getPosts())
}
```

However, I sometimes need to call multiple queries in a single file, so I would like to use the `useQueries` hook along with the custom hooks. But when I try to use the custom hooks as the `queryFn`, React throws me an error saying I can't call a hook inside the function 'queryFn'.

```
const queries = useQueries([
    {
        queryKey: 'posts',
        queryFn: () => usePosts
    },
    {
        queryKey: ['post', id],
        queryFn: () => usePost(id)
    }
])
// Failed to compile, 'usePost' is called in function 'queryFn' that is neither a React component nor custom hook
```

How would we be able to use `useQueries` with custom query hooks?

Comment: I'm not sure how `react-query` works, but you're calling the `usePost` hook in the second object, which is not allowed in React outside of a component render function. Note that, in your code, the first `queryFn` is a 'function that returns a function', while the other `queryFn` is not. I think `queryFn: () => () => usePost(id)` might be what you want.

Comment: @crizzis thank you, but there is still an error. The hook cannot be called inside a callback.

Answer (score 2):

This is simply a restriction by the [Rule of Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-from-react-functions) in React, that hooks can only be called inside React function components and other React custom hooks.

There are two options to overcome this issue in my opinion:

1. combine `usePost` and `usePosts` in another custom hook

```js
// useAllPosts.js
const useAllPosts = (id: string) => {
  const { data: post } = usePost(id);
  const { data: posts } = usePosts();

  return {
      post,
      posts
  }
}
```

2. put the fetcher functions outside of the custom hooks so you can re-use them in other components:

```js
// usePost.js
export const fetchPost = (id: string) => getPost(id);
const usePost = (id: string) => {
  return useQuery(['posts', id], fetchPost)
}

// usePosts.js
export const fetchPosts = () => getPosts();
const usePosts = () => {
  return useQuery(['posts'], () => getPosts())
}

// SomeComponent.jsx
import { fetchPost } from 'usePost';
import { fetchPosts } from 'usePosts';
function SomeComponent() {
  const queries = useQueries([
    {
      queryKey: 'posts',
      queryFn: fetchPosts
    },
    {
      queryKey: ['post', id],
      queryFn: fetchPost
    }
  ]);
}
```